# Employ environments to handle package-data in package-functions

Tags: r

I recently wrote a R extension. The functions use data contained in the package and must therefore load them. Subroutines also need to access the data.

This is the approach taken:

```
main<- function(...){
    data(data)
    sub <- function(...,data=data){...}
...
}
```

I'm unhappy with the fact that the data resides in `.GlobalEnv` so it still hangs around when the function had terminated (also undermining the downpassing via argument concept).

Please put me on the right track! How do you employ environments, when you have to handle package-data in package-functions?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the edit. You made it obvious that it was very unclear what I want. Hope this is a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that you are looking for the `LazyData` directive in your namepace:

```
LazyData: yes
```

Othewise, `data` has the `envir` argument you can use to control in which environment you want to load your data, so for example if you wanted the data to be loaded inside `main`, you could use :

```
main<- function(...){
    data(data, envir = environment() )
    sub <- function(...,data=data){...}
    ...
}
```

Comment: True, but instead of `data`, `environment` resides in `.GlobalEnv` then. Found no way to load data with `data()` or `load()` into an environment for which `parent=emptyenv()`. But anyway, is your proposed solution of making data available the accepted/foreseen method? thank you Roman.

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour you describe. Nothing resides on `.GlobalEnv` for me. Maybe this is what you are looking for `data( data, envir = new.env(parent = emptyenv() ) )`

Comment: After loading the package and executing function `main()`, `ls()` would give `data`. So data resides in `.GlobalEnv`, doesn't it? I didn't test it, but I suppose in your example `ls()` would yield `environment`. That is, what is bugging me! (using default NAMESPACE settings)

Comment: But I did test it. And it does not.

Comment: hmmm...need to trace this. thanks for the test.  That is probably the reason I'm so alone with this question. In theory, `data` should  cease to exist when `main()` terminates, along with all contained environments, just as you say, so there is something wrong on my side. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If the data is needed for your functions, not for the user of the package, it should be saved in a file called `sysdata.rda` located in the R directory.

From R extensions:

> Two exceptions are allowed: if the R subdirectory contains a file
>   sysdata.rda (a saved image of R objects: please use suitable
>   compression as suggested by tools::resaveRdaFiles) this will be
>   lazy-loaded into the namespace/package environment – this is intended
>   for system datasets that are not intended to be user-accessible via
>   data.

Comment: this is also good to know and might come in handy for future projects. thanks. Here, I just wanted my function from my package simply to leave the environment as it found it. But due to the nature of `data()` to write to `envir = .GlobalEnv` as per default, it wont. `data(data, envir = environment() )` just did the job

Comment: It took a very long time to find this info.